# Modified gower distance in R

Tags: r, distance, vegan

I have a mixed data (categorical and continuous) and I want to compute the modified Gower coefficient using the vegandist command

```
library(vegan)
vegdist(mydata, "altGower")
```

However, the following error appears:

```
Error in rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I guess it is because the column for the categorical variables are factor variables and non-numeric. If this is the problem is there any other package I can compute these distance using the modified Gower?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you want; are you asking for this adjustment to a new multiplicative scale (what I know as modified gower) *only* for the continuous variables? If so, you can this trivially using the `distance()` function in my analogue package **if** you apply the transformation as described in Anderson et al Ecology Letters 2006 to only the continuous variables. It's going to be difficult to interpret what this coefficient means though: putting quantitative variables on some new multiplicative scale whilst retaining matching for categorical or binary vars.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `vegan::vegdist()` with mixed data (this is documented). You should use either `cluster::daisy()` or `FD::gowdis()` which are able to handle mixed data. Functions differ in coding categorical data: there are several options in `gowdis()` (`FD` package). The `cluster` package is officially recommended and is probably already installed in your **R**.

Comment: gowdis is useful, however, I cannot use the Modified Gower distance with this code. Do you know if there is another one in which I can use also altGower as in vegdist?

Comment: @user2246905 You can use the modified Gower coefficient with `gowdis()`; notice that the log-transformation of Anderson et al 2006 is something entirely separate from the calculation of the the dissimilarity. In vegan we didn;t include the log transforming code in `vegdist()` but in the `decostand()` function. Hence you could apply, if you really want to, the log-transformation to the quantitative variables using `decostand()` and then pass all the data to `gowdis()`.